# Asymptotics of a combinatorial series

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, asymptotics, special-functions

I am interested in the exact asymptotics of the following combinatorial series (which arises from the study of a Markov chain):
$$F(q):=\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{q^{k^2}}{(q;q)_k^2}\quad \mbox{as } q \to 1^{-},$$
where $(q;q)_k:=(1-q)(1-q^2)\cdots(1-q^k)$ is the $q$-Pochhammer function.
To be more precise, can we get the exact leading order $f(1-q)$ for some explicit function $f$,
i.e. $F(q)/f(1-q) \to 1$ as $q \to 1^{-}$?

Comment: This is well known to be equal to the partition generating function, for which asymptotics are well known (you can find them say on Wikipedia). To see that this is equal to the generating function of the partition numbers, think about categorizing Young diagrams according to the largest square which fits in the bottom-left corner: the k-th summand in your sum corresponds to a k by k square.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. This seems to be slightly different from the partition generating function since the numerator is $q^{k^2}$, if my understanding is correct.

Comment: It is well known that  $$1+\sum_{k \ge 1} \frac{q^{k^2}}{(q;q)_k^2}=\prod_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1-q^n}.$$ This is often called the "Durfee square identity." See, for example, https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/jlms/s2-3.3.563 .