# Tail asymptotics of Durfee square identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

This post is related to the problem [Asymptotics of a combinatorial series](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/388650/asymptotics-of-a-combinatorial-series?noredirect=1#comment989764_388650)

According to the Durfee square identity:
$$\sum_{k \ge 0} \frac{q^{k^2}}{(q;q)_k^2} (q;q)_{\infty} = 1,$$
where $(q;q)_k$ is the q-Pochhammer symbol.
I would like to know for $q < 1$, if there is a tight upper bound for $\sum_{k \ge n} \frac{q^{k^2}}{(q;q)_k^2} (q;q)_{\infty}$ as $n$ is large.
It is easy to see that
$$\sum_{k \ge n} \frac{q^{k^2}}{(q;q)_k^2} (q;q)_{\infty} \le \sum_{k \ge n} \frac{q^{k^2}}{(q;q)_{\infty}}.$$
The sum $\sum_{k \ge n} q^{k^2}$ can be bounded by $q^{n^2}/(1-q^{2n})$ via a geometric sequence with quotient $q^{2n}$.
So this tail is bounded by $\frac{q^{n^2}}{(q;q)_{\infty}(1-q^{2n})}$ (independent of the value of $q$).

My question is whether we can do better to get a tighter bound in the regime $q \to 1^{-}$.
(By a classical result of Watson, $(q;q)_{\infty} \sim \sqrt{2 \pi (1-q)} \exp\left(-\frac{\pi^2}{6(1-q)} \right)$ as $q \to 1^{-}$.)